# Is there a way to fold less than a line in vim?

Tags: vim, latex, folding

since I´m doing a lot of latex editing in vim, I was wondering if it´s possible to fold only parts of a line.

For example:
I´d like to fold "\section{Hello}" simply to "Hello"(in another color) or \footnote{hi!} to "[hi!]" or even just "[1]".

Is that somehow possible? It doesn´t necessarily have to use folds, just some kind of "alias" or so would do it, since I just want to improve readability of my text.

Do you have any idea how to realize this?

Thanks for your help!

I found out so far, that it is possible to change the text in folds so I could solve the section part creating just a one line fold with a different text as in
[I want to customize the text vim shows in collapsed folds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009979/i-want-to-customize-the-text-vim-shows-in-collapsed-folds)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the trick you mentioned to manipulate the foldtext.

Now `:set foldminlines=0` in order to enable folding a single line.

Create a single line fold to test with using <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>

Subsequently fold/open (<kbd>z</kbd><kbd>[cCM]</kbd> or <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>[oOR]</kbd>) it and test your foldtext expression until it suits your needs.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I´ll try this for sections etc., for the rest I think intuited´s hint will work better.

Comment: Absolutely. I'm impressed with the bleeding edge features that intuited knows about!

Answer (score 3):

This sort of thing can apparently be done using the [conceal patch](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Patch_to_conceal_parts_of_lines), which has been rolled into vim 7.3.  It allows certain parts of the text to be, well, *concealed* from view.

**caveat:** I don't code (la)?tex, I haven't upgraded to vim 7.3, and I've never used the conceal patch.

Of course, knowledge of the conceal patch's existence, while no doubt terribly exciting, only gets you part way.  A [blog post](http://b4winckler.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/using-the-conceal-vim-feature-with-latex/), which I admittedly didn't really read, may be of further assistance.  It looks like they're doing something somewhat different from what you're aiming to accomplish: using conceal to map latex-denoted symbols to their corresponding unicode characters.  But it might be helpful nonetheless and serve as a starting point for building a custom tex syntax file that uses conceal to accomplish your goal.

Actually, it looks like the latex syntax file for 7.3 may already be using *conceal* to remap characters.  [This mailing list thread](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/f1a38e084967c750?pli=1) has a bit more information.

Comment: Thank you for this information! I haven´t read the details yet, but at the first glance, this seems to be exactly what I´m looking for.

Comment: Like I mentioned: I'm impressed with the bleeding edge features that intuited knows about!

Answer (score 0):

[vim-latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php) offers some folding, for me it is enough, see [folding](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-folding.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I´m already using vim-latex, and I think it´s very good, but I use a lot of footnotes and it´s annoying to have them in the text, so I´m trying to change that.